# Apt and package conflicts

Tags: debian, installation, yum, apt

I have spent some time researching, and as I could not find anyone with the same issue I figured I might as well ask.

I have two packages X and X-1. X-1 is essentially an upgrade from the previous package but with a different name to prevent automating updates. As its providing a bit different functionality I do not want people with package X installed to install X-1 as it will break everything they did using package X.

I have declared "Conflicts" in control file for package build, as well as gave a shot to "Breaks". Even a preinst script was tried out (but it won't help as it removes the old package before running preinst for the new one) but I cannot get this thing to work.

Yum respects the conflict and displays the appropriate message - but apt will only display a prompt about deleting the package X in order to install - but I want apt to respect the conflict and refuse to continue instead of just displaying a prompt.

Is this just the way apt works (I tired with other conflicting packages and they are displaying the same behaviour) or is there a way for me to tell apt to respect that setting?